# How to prevent char repetition with Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I try to prevent repetition of the dot char '.' and allowing only numbers/letters

e.g.

```
"blah...blah".matches(rex)) //false
 "..blablah".matches(rex)) //false
"blablah..".matches(rex)) //false
"blab.lah".matches(rex)) //true
"bla.blah".matches(rex)) //true
```

I tried using:
`^(?!\.\.)([a-zA-Z0-9._\-]*)$`
but it works only for the second example, how can I make it work?

Comment: Do you have to use regex? (There might be a simpler option)

Comment: did you work it out?

Comment: Yes I prefer regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close, you need to adjust the lookahead to `(?!.*\\.{2})`, so the overall regex is `^(?!.*\\.{2})([a-zA-Z0-9._\-]*)$`. Note that you don't need the anchors when used with `.matches()` as it tries to match the whole string.

If you don't want any of the non-letters/numbers to consecutively repeat, you can instead use `(?!.*([._-])\\1+)` for the lookeahed.

Comment: Are you sure this is working? I tested it on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html but everything was true.

Comment: Backslash hell maybe? In my answer backslashes are escaped (like they need to be when used as java string), but that site needs them unescaped: `^(?!.*\.{2})([a-zA-Z0-9._\-]*)$`

Comment: Yep, I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a back-reference to a captured character:

```
if (str.matches("(([\\w.-])(?!\\2))*"))
    // no chars are repeated
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/ydWl3N5utQ).

Note that "letters, numbers, underscore, dot and dash" can be written as `[\\w.-]`.
`\w == [a-zA-Z0-9_]` and the dash doesn't need escaping if it appears first or last.

Comment: Your example is very close to what I ask however it detects all repetition,
Let me be more specific, I want to prevent only dot(.) char repetition, it can appear more than once but not sequentially.
I allow all a-zA-Z0-9 and -(dash) _(underscore) \(backslash ) and .(dot but not in sequence).
I ask this because I want to prevent path traversal.

Comment: I wrote backslash I meant regular slash

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replace()` to remove all the `'.'` characters.

```
String a="blah...blah";
a = a.replace(".", "");
System.out.println(a);
```

the output of this is `blahblah`.